# jooq return query with incorrect values

Tags: java, insert, jooq

I want to insert into database table data using following jooq based code to generate query:

```java
Factory jf = getJooqFactory();
int surveyId = jf.nextval(SURVEY_ID_SEQ).intValue();
jf.insertInto(SURVEY)
        .set(SURVEY.ID, surveyId)
        .set(SURVEY.NAME, survey.getName())
        .set(SURVEY.IDML, Factory.val(idml, SQLDataType.CLOB))
        .execute();
```

The problem is that when I print the query using this code

```java
System.out.println(jf.insertInto(SURVEY)
            .set(SURVEY.ID, null)
            .set(SURVEY.NAME, null)
            .set(SURVEY.IDML, null)
            .getSQL());
```

what I get is query with question marks instead of values.

```sql
insert into "collect"."survey" ("id", "name", "idml") values (?, ?, ?)
```

When I print values of variables separately they are all correct. Even if I insert String values manually in .set() getSQL() return question marks.

Comment: I don't know a lot about jOOQ, but I suspect that it's using parameterised SQL to do its work.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement .  Unless you're getting question marks going into your database, it's nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`org.jooq.Query.getSQL()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Query.html#getSQL%28%29) renders SQL exactly as it is rendered to the JDBC [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html). Prepared statements in Java expect bind variables to be rendered as question marks: `?`. The actual bind values are then set using methods, such as in this example

```
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(
  "insert into collect.survey (id, name, idml) values (?, ?, ?)");
stmt.setInt(1, surveyId);
stmt.setString(2, survey.getName());
stmt.setString(3, idml);
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

If you want to see the generated SQL with inlined bind values, you can use the factory's [`Factory.renderInlined()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/Factory.html#renderInlined%28org.jooq.QueryPart%29) method:

```
String sql = jf.renderInlined(
  jf.insertInto(SURVEY)
    .set(SURVEY.ID, surveyId)
    .set(SURVEY.NAME, survey.getName())
    .set(SURVEY.IDML, val(idml, SQLDataType.CLOB))
);
```

There is also a `getSQL(boolean)` method on the `Query` object, to render SQL with inlined bind variables:

```
jf.insertInto(SURVEY)
  .set(SURVEY.ID, surveyId)
  .set(SURVEY.NAME, survey.getName())
  .set(SURVEY.IDML, val(idml, SQLDataType.CLOB))
  .getSQL(true);
```

Learn more about JDBC's `PreparedStatement` here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html